# Creating an IFrame in sencha

Tags: javascript, iframe, extjs

Well I'm trying to add an IFrame to a tab bar using sencha/ext6 **modern**.

Currently my try is to have a tab bar like:

```
Ext.define('Heren5Frontend.view.main.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    xtype: 'app-main',

    controller: 'main',
    viewModel: 'main',

    defaults: {
        tab: {
            iconAlign: 'top'
        }
    },

    tabBarPosition: 'top',

    items: [{
            title: 'Aanmelden wedstrijd',
            //iconCls: 'x-fa fa-users',
            items:[{
                xtype: "attendenceframe",
                id: "frameId",
                src: "http://google.com",
            }]
        }
    ]
});
```

With the frame as:

```
Ext.define('Heren5.view.main.AttendenceFrame', {
    extend: 'Ext.ux.IFrame',
    xtype: 'attendenceframe',
    requires: [
        'Ext.ux.IFrame',
    ],
});
```

This however fails, since the namespace isn't found. Updating `app.json` should make it work?

```
"requires": [
    "font-awesome",
    "ext-ux"
],
```

However this still fails with the error message at building:

```
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExNotFound: Unknown definition for dependency : Ext.ux.IFrame
[ERR]   at or
[ERR] g.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ext.ux.IFrame` is not part of the modern toolkit. If you check the documentation, you see that `Ext.ux.IFrame` is marked with a [C] (classic) in the search, and not with an [M] (modern). It seems there is no similar component available for the modern toolkit.

You can try whether copying over the [code](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/src/IFrame.js.html) into your project resolves the issue.